# If $B$ is a closed set then every sequence converges to a point in $B$

Tags: real-analysis

If $B$ is a closed set then every sequence converges to a point in $B$ is true o false?
I think its false because we know that every closed interval is a closed set
then if we take the interval $A=[-1,1]$ and the sequence

$x_n= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             -1 &   if  & n   \text{is pair}\\
             \\ 1 &  if  & n \text{is odd} \\
             \\ 
             \end{array}
   \right.$

then $\{x_n\}\subset A $ but $x_n$ doesnt converges

Comment: Right (mais en Anglais, on dit "even", pas "pair").

Comment: In the setting of a compact closed set, such as the interval $A$ you chose, one can prove every sequence has a convergent *subsequence*.  But if knew only a sequence is in closed set $B$, then a sequence might not have that (e.g. the sequence of positive integers in closed set $\mathbb R$, the real numbers).

Comment: One can also show that IF it converges it converges to a point in the set.

Comment: @GerryMyerson « C’est dommage! » It would be convenient for us, the poor Frenchies.